# Data truncation error when using a named parameter for an int

Tags: java, sql, ibm-midrange

I am getting a Data truncation error, even before my query runs.  If I hard code the int value in the query it works.  If I replace that with a named parameter, I get Data truncation.  Is this the correct format?

So, why does this work:
`WHERE MDRW01 > '0' AND MDRW01 <= (755795 * .001)`

And this does not?
`WHERE MDRW01 > '0' AND MDRW01 <= (:totalMiles * .001)`

Answer (score 0):

An int doesn't have a decimal.  When you multiply .001

- your parameter it is resulting in  a decimal and not an int. Try changing your parameter to a decimal?